# Traveller's guide to Ballmer's Peak

Tags: discussion, fun

It's this time of the year again – cold and damp outside, impending in-laws, that old hobby project in dire need of refactoring, and the fifth newbie question on why pointers aren't arrays, or why code that "is working perfectly" still doesn't handle end-of-file correctly.

Only one way out: A trip to the supply cabinet, and mix up the old happy juice.

What's your favourite recipe? What works and what doesn't?

I'll start. This one is a classic, though I refer to it as *The Uncaught Exception*:

- Two units of whisky (no 'e')
- One teaspoon of honey
- Careful amounts of hot water (to taste)

Best used when: After opening a question, and before typing the response.

Counter indications: Does not mix well with Boost.

Comment: If you have the opportunity, a [McGraths No. 5](http://mcgrathsirishales.com/) is good for achieving the ol' Ballmers Peak.

Comment: @JMK: Looks very nice, though I should have added that it's safe to assume it's past 11am.

Answer (score 4):

Since saying "a shot of tequila" is a bit too short, I'll go with a mixed drink:

### Crown and Ginger

I know, some people long ago decided that Coke should be *the* Crown mixer, but they're just plain wrong. Not only does it taste better, but it gives me another reason to buy [magic skyjuice](http://theoatmeal.com/blog/beverage_options).

- 1 part Crown Royal
- 1 part Ginger Ale
- Slice of lime (optional, but don't cheat with bottled lime juice)

**Best used when** : At any keyboard that isn't in an office

**Contraindications** : Can lead to accidental [refuctoring](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)

*Disclaimer: Many other whiskies work just as well (or better), but Crown has a good price/quality ratio around here.*

Comment: Not sure if to -1 for the Canadian whisky, or to +1 for suggesting something useful to do with said whisky (I actually have a surplus of this particular one, for complicated reasons). Anyway a +1 for the side effects warning.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't *really* expect the disclaimer to prevent comments disparaging the choice of whiskies.